# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed while trying to delete an object related

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

So I have these models in my app:

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Vendedor


class Comissao(models.Model):
    porcentagem = models.FloatField()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.porcentagem)


class Venda(models.Model):
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey(Vendedor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    comissao_venda = models.ForeignKey(Comissao, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data_venda = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    valor_venda = models.FloatField()
    descricao_venda = models.CharField(max_length=60)


    @property
    def valor_a_receber(self):
        return self.comissao_venda.porcentagem * self.valor_venda


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vendedor)
```

and my problem is when I try to delete `Comissao` object I get this error:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I´ve been hours stuck in this error, hope can someone help me...XD

Comment: This is due to the `DO_NOTHING`: `ForeignKey`s are enforced at the database level: that means that a `commissao_venda` needs to refer to a valid `Comissao`, but if you remove the `Commisao`, then that is no longer the case, hence the database rejects this.

Comment: then what can i do i already tried using the `models.SET_DEFAULT` and setting a default of 0 in the `porcentagem` field but i get this error too: `sales.Venda.comissao_venda: (fields.E321) Field specifies on_delete=SET_DEFAULT, but has no default value.
        HINT: Set a default value, or change the on_delete rule.`

Comment: well as the error says, you will need to set a default then. How did you set a default?

Comment: here is what i did in the `ForeignKey` but i still get the error...:`comissao_venda = models.ForeignKey(Comissao, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0)`

Comment: you likely should *first* set `default=0`, then migrate, and then set `on_delete=` to `SET_DEFAULT`.

Comment: i did what you mentioned and still get the same error..

Comment: hold on, but `0` makes not much sense, since normally primary keys start at `1`, so that will raise an integrity error.

Comment: yea you right, because with this we are using the id, because its a `ForeignKey` right?

Comment: yes, unless you specify `to_field=...`, but that is probably not relevant here.

Comment: soo using a `SET_DEFAULT` is not a go to here nor `SET_NULL` right?

Comment: if you use `null=True`, then you can use `SET_NULL`.. If I try this locally with `default=1`, it works for `SET_DEFAULT`.

Comment: the problem is that in my program, the value 1 in that field wont be the right choice, i think i found a link, gonna give it a try: https://dbslusser.medium.com/setting-defaults-for-django-foreign-key-fields-c53cffb25a8c

Comment: you can also use `SET(callable)`, where `callable` is a function that then should *generate* a value to fill in.

Comment: That is true, both worked, should i put your answer rght=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the [**`DO_NOTHING`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING): `ForeignKey`s are enforced at the database level: that means that a `commissao_venda` needs to refer to a valid `Comissao`, but if you remove the `Commisao`, then that is no longer the case, hence the database rejects this. Or, as is documented:

> Take no action. If your database backend **enforces referential integrity**, this will **cause an `IntegrityError`** unless you manually add an SQL `ON DELETE` constraint to the database field.

Often `DO_NOTHING` is not a good idea anyway. The question is what do you want to do with the `Venda` in case the `Comissao` it refers to is removed? Two popular options are:

1. [**`CASCADE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE), in that case the `Venda`(s) that refer to that `Comissao` are removed *as well*. This can trigger other removals, and thus a single `Comissao` can eventually trigger removing a lot of records from several tables; or
2. [**`SET_NULL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL), you will have to make your field NULLable, by setting [**`null=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null). In that case the `commissao_venda` will be set to `NULL`/`None`. The field thus then looks like:

   ```
   comissao_venda = models.ForeignKey(Comissao, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   ```

Other options are [**`PROTECT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT), [**`RESTRICT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT), [**`SET_DEFAULT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_DEFAULT), and [**`SET(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET). It of course all depends on what *you* want to happen in that case.